# How to troubleshoot ASP.NET Core 6 MVC view problem when using ZipFile

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, c#-6.0, system.io.compression.zipfile

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app to test viewing various files. The tests were performed in Visual Studio 2022 on localhost.

The test steps include:

1. Using a sample file `example03.docx` and save it in `.htm` format.
2. It created 2 items `example03.htm` and a folder `example03_files`
3. Copied the file and folder to `/wwwroot/files` folder
4. In the app, in the `HomeController`, add an action method `ViewWordFile` (see CODE #1)
5. Created a view `ViewWordFile.cshtml` (see CODE #2)
6. Test the code and everything worked as expected

I encountered problems after trying to compress the `example03.htm` and related folder into `example03.zip` file. I then tried to unzip that file in a `ViewWordFile` action method (see details in problem description section below)

**CODE #1:**

```
public IActionResult ViewWordFile()
{
    return View();
}
```

**CODE #2:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View Office File";
}

<div class="container">
    <h3>View MS Word Document</h3>
    <p>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <iframe src='https://localhost:7131/files/example03.htm' width='100%' height='650px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
    </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Problem description:

1. Added 2 subfolders `/wwwroot/files/zipped` and `/wwwroot/files/unzip`
2. Manually created zip file `example03.zip` and copied it to the `/files/zipped` folder
3. In order to decompress the zip file, I added a method `unpackFile` in the `HomeController` (see CODE #3)
4. Modify the `ViewWordFile` action method (see CODE 4)
5. When trace the code during execution, the unzip worked fine and unzipped files were placed in the `/files/unzip` folder
6. After these changes, the `ViewWordFile` action stopped working. During tracking, I could see the view was activated, when I put a breakpoint in the code block at the top. But, nothing was displayed. It looked like it was still at home page.
7. I thought it might be a file permission issue. I removed code calling `UnpackFile` in `ViewWordFile` action (as in CODE #3) and keep using files in `/unzip` folder. The page started working again. It showed file permission was not the actual problem.
8. I suspect there was something with calling `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory`. I changed code to call this method inside of `ViewWordFile` action (see CODE #5). The problem happened again and page stopped working.

It seemed that the `ZipFile` method interfered with the view. But I was unable to figure out the actual reason.

Any help or suggestions for troubleshooting will be greatly appreciated.

**CODE #3**

```
private bool UnpackFile (string zipFile, string unzipDir)
{
    bool isOk = false;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(zipFile))
    {
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, unzipDir, true);
        isOk = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**CODE #4**

```
public IActionResult ViewWordFile()
{
    string zipFile = Path.Combine(_hostEnv.WebRootPath, "files/zipped", "example03.zip");
    string unzipDir = Path.Combine(_hostEnv.WebRootPath, "files/unzip");
    UnpackFile(zipFile, unzipDir);

    return View();
}
```

**CODE #5**

```
public IActionResult ViewWordFile()
{
    string zipFile = Path.Combine(_hostEnv.WebRootPath, "files/zipped", "example03.zip");
    string unzipDir = Path.Combine(_hostEnv.WebRootPath, "files/unzip");
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, unzipDir, true);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: If you directly access the page inside the browser, will it work?

Comment: Yes.  the decompressed file does work when accessing the page directly from the browser.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the status codes inside the browser's F12 network trace?

Comment: I started web app in Chrome and opened "develop tools" and "network" tab.  When I tested of viewing the unzipped file, the last 2 entires in listed info under network tab showed the status code 101.  I am not sure whether this is the correct way of checking the status code.  If not, please let me know how to do it correctly.

Comment: 101 normally means the websocket upgrade. If possible could you please share the network trace?

Comment: I have captured the network track in a .HAR file.  But, I am unable to attached the file to this post.  I also tried to save Console log. It did not have tracing data. Please let me know what I should do in order to share the network trace.  Thanks.

Comment: You capture the image for that html file's  status codes or response details.

Comment: Request URL: ws://localhost:51568/WebViewer/
HTTP Version: HTTP/1.1
Request method: GET
Headers:
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection Upgrade
Host localhost:51568
Origin https://localhost:7131
Pragma no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key 7tefxGAIcHonWVyCbS3pSA==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol .......
Sec-WebSocket-Version 13
Upgrade websocket
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Comment: I just pasted the details of last entry with 101 status code in last comment.  I got the info using Google .HAR analyzer to view the .HAR file I created.  I am not sure whether it contains any usefule info.